# Find connected component for two variables in Stata

Tags: grouping, stata

Suppose I have two id variables in my survey, id1 and id2. I want to consolidate all observations at a level defined by two variables, ie join all the observations that have the id1 or id2. More precisely, two individuals are defined to be pairwise related when they share the same id1 or id2, and I want to define a new variable id3 such that observation1 and observation2 have the same id3 iff there is a **chain** of pairwise related observations from observation 1 to observation 2. This is  a particular application of the the problem of finding connected component.

Intuitively, this would be similar to a command `egen id = group(var1 var2)` that uses the **OR** logic rather than the **AND** logic. How should one do it in stata?

Comment: I'd recommend you post whatever code you've tried (if anything apart from `egen, group()`) and an example describing your current and desired databases.

Comment: This is not so clear-cut as your example implies. What about (Omar, 1), (Omar, 2), (Gabriel, 2). What rule applies then? The trouble is that "or" is greedy.

Comment: Hello Nick Cox. Thanks for answering the question -  a Stata user dream came true. However I don't understand your point. Is 1/2 the equivalent of var2 in your exemple? If yes, then every observation in your example should be in the same ID (this is exactly the point of the example) - this function should greedy, indeed. In the worst case, there could be only one group for the whole dataset. However, in the case I'm interested in, this is not a worry.

Comment: You are correct in interpreting my example. I don't see the need to echo the details of US zip codes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer to my question. The program a2group, written by Amine Ouazad, does just that. It can be installed via a2reg

Comment: The user-written command `a2group`, found in the `A2REG` module (by Amine Ouazad) can be downloaded running `findit a2group`.